ffmpeg - Remove first few seconds from one of the audio streams
I have a .mkv file with multiple audio and subtitle streams.
One of these streams has unsynchronized audio, and I want to move it 10 seconds, how can I do it?

You can move (delay) the audio track by N seconds using the following command:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -itsoffset N -i input.mp4 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy output.mp4


Separate the audio/video, extracting the audio to .wav.
ffmpeg -i file.mkv -vn file_audio.wav && ffmpeg -i file.mkv -an -c copy file_video.mkv

Trim audio with -ss to set start time while re-compressing audio.  You can check the source audio type with ffprobe file.mkv, if needed.
ffmpeg -i file_audio.wav -ss 00:00:10.00 -c:a aac file_new_audio.aac

Re-mux the audio and video.
ffmpeg -i file_video.mkv -i file_new_audio.aac -c copy final_mux.mkv

Delete intermediate files.  Complete.

So, it is not possible without an aux file?

Not if you need it literally truncated from the file first.  You have to demux to edit the audio, it's required.  Another, more accurate, method: open the audio with Audacity, select and trim it.  You could ffprobe file.mkv and get the exact runtime, including ms HH:MM:SS.ms.  In audacity you can select it starting from the end, then set the start time to match exactly where the video runtime starts by subtracting the video runtime from the audio. You'll know where to start the selection, exactly.  It will mux, already synced.
